# Если есть символ {} else {}

Tags: php

Как через if сделать следующее: если перед строкой есть "-" выполнить 1 запрос. Ну, а если нет - else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(исхожу из того, что имеется в виду первый символ в строке)*

Строки в php имеют примерно такой же интерфейс доступа, как и массивы (и, наверняка, являются просто массивами символов "под капотом"). Обратится к любому символу можно так же, как к элементу массива:

```
$dummyString = 'Yarr!';
$firstSymbol = $dummyString[0];
```

В примере выше переменная `$firstSymbol` будет содержать **строку**, состоящую из первого символа строки в переменной `$dummyString` ('Y'; в PHP нет типа "символ", есть только строка, в то время как многие другие языки в этом случае вернули бы не строку, а именно символ).

Полученнный таким образом символ (строку из одного символа) можно использовать как угодно, например, сравнивать:

```
if ($dummyString[0] === 'Y') {
    echo 'I think we\'re dealing with a proper Yarr';
}
```

Таким образом, вопрос решается следующим образом:

```
$controlString = '...'; // исследуемая строка, задается где-то ранее в скрипте
if ($controlString[0] === '-') {
    // первый символ соответствует, выполняется один запрос
} else {
    // выполняется другой запрос
}
```